# Parse does not show all my file once I add a new file

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

My web application allows users to create and view files they have created. When the user logs in they can see all the files they created, however when the users creates a new file, and then clicks to view all the files, the newly created file is not there.

Here is my code for saving the file in parse:

```
router.post('/newfile', function(req, res) {
  var usercode = req.body.code;
  console.log(usercode);
  newname = req.body.name;
  console.log(newname);
  var bytes = [];
  var doc = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < usercode.length; i++) {
      bytes.push(usercode.charCodeAt(i));
  };
  console.log("passed byetes");
  var parseFile = new Parse.File(newname, bytes);
  parseFile.save();
  var FileClass = Parse.Object.extend("File");
  var newFile = new FileClass();
  newFile.save({
      user: Parse.User.current(),
      fileName: newname,
      javaFile: parseFile
  });
  var newFileClass = Parse.Object.extend("File");
  var query = new Parse.Query(newFileClass);
  query.find(function(results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var object = results[i];
          var codefile = object.get('javaFile');
          temp = codefile.name();
          name = temp.split("-").pop();
          url = codefile.url();
          doc[name] = url;
      }
  }).then(function() {
      console.log("Inside then(function()");
      console.log(doc);
      res.json({
          FIles: JSON.stringify(doc)
      });
  });
});
```

So once the new file is saved, I do a `parse.query.find`  to get all the files again. When the program comes to the line `console.log(doc)` it should print all the files including the new one, but it only prints the old files. However once I log out and log back in the new file is there. How do I fix this such that after the user saves the new file it appears along with the other files?

Answer (score 0):

save() runs asynchronously, so all of that code after save() runs before it, before the query will be able to show you anything new .  Restructure like this:

```
save().then(function () {
    // everything that follows your save() here
    var FileClass = Parse.Object.extend("File");
    // etc.
});
```

EDIT - better code formatting in your edit revealed that there are several asynch functions being attempted, use promises to keep them straight...

```
router.post('/newfile', function(req, res) {
  var usercode = req.body.code;
  console.log(usercode);
  newname = req.body.name;
  console.log(newname);
  var bytes = [];
  var doc = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < usercode.length; i++) {
      bytes.push(usercode.charCodeAt(i));
  };
  console.log("passed byetes");
  var parseFile = new Parse.File(newname, bytes);
  parseFile.save();
  var FileClass = Parse.Object.extend("File");
  var newFile = new FileClass();
  newFile.save().then(function () {
      user: Parse.User.current(),
      fileName: newname,
      javaFile: parseFile

      var newFileClass = Parse.Object.extend("File");
      var query = new Parse.Query(newFileClass);
      return query.find();
  }).then(function(results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var object = results[i];
          var codefile = object.get('javaFile');
          temp = codefile.name();
          name = temp.split("-").pop();
          url = codefile.url();
          doc[name] = url;
      }
      console.log("Inside then(function()");
      console.log(doc);
      res.json({
          FIles: JSON.stringify(doc)
      });
  });
});
```

I find even this a little tough on the eyes.  I can't be sure I didn't just inadvertently code in a syntax error for you.  An even better restructure would be to divide this big function into several promise-returning smaller ones, named by what they promise to do.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the formatting. So I fixed it, and its working however I can't seem to send `doc` to the client side. I have tried res.send() and res.json.

Comment: If you console log `JSON.stringify(doc)` does it look okay?

Comment: Yea, if I do console.log(JSON.stringify(doc)) I get the correct stuff. Meaning the new file I created is there

Comment: Ok good, so the files is getting saved, which is what this question is about.  Not seeing it on the client must have something to do with the client.  How are you making the request?  In other words, if you just respond `res.json({ "foo":"bar" });` can you see that on the client?